# Textfield instead of fieldlabel in combobox extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

So usually when creating a combobox, you can add a fieldlabel beside it. Is it possible to have an empty textfield instead of a fieldlabel there in extjs? I have a form with comboboxes, but instead of fieldlabel beside each of them I want a textfield beside each of them. Is this possible without actually creating individual textfields outside the form?

Comment: The labels are made by the [`labelable` mixin](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable), which has a dozen or so templates you could change.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You can have checkbox without label and put a textfield next to it. Of course it depends on the layout of the form. If you want them to be next to each other, you can wrap them in a fieldcontainer.

Comment: I know I can have a combobox without label and creating a textfield next to it. But then I have to manually position each individual textfield so it stands next to the comboxes. Just wondering if there a better way to implement it, since all the comboboxes are in a form.

Answer (score 0):

No there's no way to do that in extjs now. But you can create this as a new component and keep it for yourself for later uses. This component should contain 1 textfield with "hiddenLabel:true" and 1 combobox with "hiddenLabel:true", stored in a CompositeField next to each others.